# Error: oDialog.open Is Not a Function

Tags: sapui5

I'm getting this error while following the [Walktrough](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/4da72985139b4b83b5f1c1e0c0d2ed5a). I can't see what's wrong with the code.

> HolaPanel.controller.js?eval:28 Uncaught TypeError: oDialog.open is not a function
>   at f.openDialog (HolaPanel.controller.js?eval:28)
>   at f.a.fireEvent (EventProvider-dbg.js:228)
>   at f.a.fireEvent (Element-dbg.js:427)
>   at f.firePress (ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:428)
>   at f.d.ontap (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3425),
>    :820:179)
>   at f.a._handleEvent (Element-dbg.js:162)
>   at constructor.U._handleEvent (UIArea-dbg.js:828)
>   at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery-dbg.js:4737)
>   at g (jquery-mobile-custom-dbg.js:1972)
>   at HTMLBodyElement.q (jquery-mobile-custom-dbg.js:2063)
>   openDialog @ HolaPanel.controller.js?eval:28
>   a.fireEvent @ EventProvider-dbg.js:228
>   a.fireEvent @ Element-dbg.js:427
>   (anonymous) @ ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:428
>   d.ontap @ Button-dbg.js:269
>   a._handleEvent @ Element-dbg.js:162
>   U._handleEvent @ UIArea-dbg.js:828
>   dispatch @ jquery-dbg.js:4737
>   g @ jquery-mobile-custom-dbg.js:1972
>   q @ jquery-mobile-custom-dbg.js:2063
>   dispatch @ jquery-dbg.js:4737
>   c3.handle @ jquery-dbg.js:4549
>   trigger @ jquery-dbg.js:7819
>   (anonymous) @ jquery-dbg.js:7903
>   each @ jquery-dbg.js:365
>   each @ jquery-dbg.js:137
>   trigger @ jquery-dbg.js:7902
>   P @ jquery-mobile-custom-dbg.js:1543
>   R @ jquery-mobile-custom-dbg.js:1553
>   dispatch @ jquery-dbg.js:4737
>   c3.handle @ jquery-dbg.js:4549

And this is my code:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <Page title="Title">
        <content>
             <Dialog
              id="idDialog"
              title="Bienvenido {/recipient/name}">
                  <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <Image
                            busy="false"
                            busyIndicatorDelay="1000"
                            visible="true"
                            src="https://www.kaufmannsf.cl/img/logos/img_kaufmann.png"
                            mode="Image"
                            backgroundSize="cover"/>                
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                  </Toolbar>
                   <beginButton>
                     <Button
                        text="{i18n>dialogCloseButtonText}"
                        press="onCloseDialog"/>
                  </beginButton>
              </Dialog>
        </content>
    </Page>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

And this is the controller of the view that contains the dialog:

```
openDialog : function () {
    var oView = this.getView();
    var oDialog = oView.byId("idDialog");
    // create dialog lazily
    if (!oDialog) {
        // create dialog via fragment factory
        oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "opensap.myapp.view.HelloDialog");
        oView.addDependent(oDialog);
    }
    oDialog.open();
},

onCloseDialog : function() {
    this.getView().byId("idDialog").close();
}
```

Also I have this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) sap-ui.core.js

I don't know if it's related with the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As @matbtt said,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48894003/5846045) the `<Page>` was killing the execution when trying to open. Delete the `<Page>` in your fragment as he said.

Then, to access the `onCloseDialog` event handler, you need to pass the controller to the Dialog when instantiating it with the `sap.ui.xmlfragment` factory function.

Just add `this` as third parameter:

```
oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.view.HelloDialog", this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your fragment defines a Page with a Dialog, but it should only contain the Dialog. The code fails as the Page does not have a function **open**. Please adjust your fragment definition and have a look into the [manual](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/04575456e15e426d81054805990c7a53).

```
<core:FragmentDefinition 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <Dialog id="idDialog" title="Bienvenido {/recipient/name}">
         ...
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: i deleted app but still with outh close mi dialog :/